# Performance issues with Exchange 2007 and Outlook 2010

Tags: performance, exchange, outlook

In my environment, I have Exchange 2007, ccr environment with 2 MB, 2 HT, and 2 CAS servers. We are currently using Outlook 2010 as our email client for the terminal server. The client is configured to connect directly to exchange, not cached mode.

Lately our users have complaints about speeds and performance in Outlook 2010, such as when they select a folder, it takes the server several minutes for the folder to display the items. Sometimes Outlook will freeze while waiting to load, and it takes several minutes to unfreeze.

Any troubleshooting ideas that I can try to diagnose what is causing this issue??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pay attention to your server IO. My instant instinct is that you're probably pegging the disks. If your storage system is overloaded, you'll be unable to answer requests in a timely way.

I personally like to make use of the [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) tools for measuring activity on Windows systems. `procexp.exe` is a handy view of system and process activity.

[image: Screenshot of IO window from ProcExp]

Comment: Here's a screen shot of my primary MB in the cluster, see any irregularities? http://s156.photobucket.com/albums/t12/jakester05/?action=view&current=Capture.png

Comment: @user1236435 Where?

Comment: http://s156.photobucket.com/albums/t12/jakester05/?action=view&current=Untitled.png

Comment: Thats a summary screen shot. Only thing I notice is the memory is nearly maxed out.

Comment: That could be an issue, especially if swapping is occurring. It will also limit disk read cache in memory. Also consider that things can be maxed out with out a full spike in the chart. Consider IOPS. I can't tell from those charts, run 'perfmon.exe' (included in Windows) and look at your Logical Disk -> Queue length charts.

Comment: I did it for current and average disk read queue length, and it's pegged at 100. Is that normal??

Comment: @user1236435 That's a sign your storage is pegged and is a limiting factor. Acquire a higher-performing disk system or add enough memory for better caching. Sufficient spare memory can also help fix read queuing.